# Windows10にApache2.4+PHP7.3環境を作りたいけれど必要なファイルが含まれていない

Tags: php, windows, apache

https://webkaru.net/php/windows-apache-php-confirmation/
こちらの記事を見ながらWindows10上にPHP7.3+Apache2.4の環境を構築しているのですが、PHPのサイトからダウンロードしたフォルダに"php6apache2_4.dll"(php6ではなく7?)がなく、configの設定ができません。([この箇所](https://webkaru.net/php/windows-apache-php-confirmation/)で躓いています)
このファイルはどこから入手することが出来ますか?
また、このサイトに書かれているPHP6系と7.3の場合で構築方法に変わるところはありますか?

Comment: Windows7ですが、PHPはこの辺が一番新しそうです。[WindowsでPHP/Apache環境構築(ダウンロード～画面を起動するまで)](https://qiita.com/uriuri7610/items/df6a05ed27b65fde499c)

Comment: 念のため「どこ」から「何というファイル」をダウンロードしたのかも書いておくとより親切かなと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

試しにPHPの公式サイトから7.3.1 Windows版をダウンロードしてみましたが、`php7apache2_4.dll`が含まれていました。数字の部分はPHPとApacheバージョンに対応しているので、参考にした記事によっては情報が古い場合があるので適時読み替える必要があります。

https://windows.php.net/download#php-7.3

VC15 x86 Thread Safe (32bit版)
php-7.3.1-Win32-VC15-x86.zip
php7apache2_4.dll